# Using polygon (simulating annotation) shapefile in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, feature-class, annotation

I received some shapefiles to create a map, and included is an 'annotation' shapefile, which contains all of the labels for the map as well as the label properties (FontName, FontSize, Angle, etc). However, I cannot figure out how to get ArcMap (v10.3) to use these label properties. I've tried googling but keep finding information how to edit attribute feature classes, but not how to use them if provided one.

Comment: Shapefiles do not support annotation features. Where did the annotation come from? What feature type is in the shape file? You might be able to get the data resupplied as an annotation feature class in a personal (or file) geodatabase or CAD file.

Comment: I was just provided with a directory containing 4 shapefiles (basemap, buildings, water, and annotation). The annotation shapefile has labels for all the streets, buildings, etc stored in the attribute table. It also includes FeatureID, SymbolID, TextString, FontName, FontSize, Bold, Angle, XOffset, YOffset, etc. These seem to be the properties included in an annotation feature class, but I have never used these and so I am not sure.

Comment: It sounds like it has the right fields but what geometry is it? The values are irrelevant without a location to pin it to.

Comment: It sounds like you have been given a point shapefile that has the attributes for creating an annotation feature class from it.  Perhaps search for techniques for doing that or ask the provider what they intended being done with the shapefile that they provided.

Comment: They are polygons. When i first add it to the map there are polygons where all the labels should be, but I do not know how to show the labels with the label properties provided in the attribute table.

Comment: If possible ask for a resupply from where you got the data from as a geodatabase feature class. It is possible to recreate the annotation with ArcObjects (or perhaps arcpy) but it would be **a lot** of work.